# is the grammar correct: did you get vaccinated?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verb-forms

is the grammar correct in the question?

> did you get vaccinated?

I know we are not supposed to use past tense for verb with **did** but I can't understand this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that a base verb should follow "did"... and it does. You have the verb '*get*'.

It's quite common to use 'get' + a verb in the past participle form, even if talking about a future event, for example "*let's get started*". Equally, you could ask "*are you going to get vaccinated?*

It would of course be entirely incorrect if you asked "did you *got*....".

Comment: @Man_From_India I haven't suggested that is the case. Trying to keep the answer simple and not over-complicate it.

Comment: @Man_From_India Can you explain what "*even if....*" means?

Comment: Hi Astralbee, sorry friend. I thought that sentence did suggest two meaning. But I was wrong. And so there was no need of keeping those misleading comments. Sorry for wasting your time and troubling you.

Comment: @Man_From_India That is very much appreciated. We're all here to help and learn.